# Linebreaks in comments don't seem to be working

Tags: support, comment, markdown, formatting

The help page says:

> End a line with two spaces to add a `<br/>` linebreak

But I did that [in my comment here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124025/working-out-the-best-score-based-on-quantity-and-ratio) and I do not see any sort of break.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Now I'll try another line break here.  
I like pie.  
I like pie.  

No, it definitely didn't work.

Comment: Test: $$\text{I like } \pi$$ $$\text{I like } \pi$$. As a workaround (which uses the math capabilities) you can put your comment in `$$`: like `$$\text{I like pie}$$`

Comment: @Aryabhata I do not understand your suggestion. Surely you are not suggesting that I make my entire comment into a math display?

Comment: It is not just meant for you, it is for anyone who comes across this issue and comes across this question. It might work for some. It might not work for you. Hence it is a comment, not an answer. You are free to not use it if it does not suit your purpose. Besides, there are probably multiple ways of getting multi line text using tex. This is just one of the ways...

Comment: I tried using `$$\quad$$` to make a space but $$\quad$$  it looks pretty bad.

Comment: Okay, I just tried several things and none of them worked. It may be a left-over from when they changed to "enter submits the comments".

Comment: @Mark: Is there a real need for a line break in your comment?

Comment: did you mean to have a link to the help page you were looking at? Specifically, [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) is the "comment" section of the editing help page. Note that "Comments support only bold, italic, code and links". In particular, linebreaks are **not** supported in comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Line breaks and many other stuff are [not supported in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/add-syntax-highlighting-and-line-breaks-to-comment-formatting). The basic design rationale is (as described by SE) that comments should be short and sweet: if you need to start a new paragraph, either you are really writing an answer (and so should be posting as such) or you are being too verbose in the comments.

Comment: Very good, thanks. I wish the documentation had made this clearer.  Clicking the "help" button while adding a comment pops up a yellow box that documents the stuff that works, but also has a "Learn more" link that points to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting . That page is in two sections, one for comments, and one not, but the distinction wasn't clear until I knew the answer.  I think a couple of `<h3>` elements would have prevented my confusion.